# Finding out individual resource planned hours from MPP

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, ms-project-2013

I have created a year long project's MPP.
Next I want to figure out planned hours for each resource.

I am using Microsoft Project Standard 2013.

What I want is to specifically point out the total planned hours for the project as a breakup of resource's planned hours.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to be looking at the "Resource Usage" view which gives, for each resource, a breakdown of the tasks allocated to them and the hours they will spend on each task both at a summary (total) level and also broken down by day.

Look on the Task menu on the left-hand side. Do you see the 'Gantt Chart' button with a dropdown? Click on the dropdown and select 'Resource Usage'

Comment: thanks for the inputs. My project has 3 major sections and I wanted to see break up for these summary tasks as well. The "Group By" filter in "Resource Usage" view did help me achieve this. Any other way of looking at the resource view you may suggest?

Comment: Not that I know of, I've always had to export the data to Excel to slice and dice it according to arbitrary groupings, but there may be more ways (Julie will know if anyone does!)

Comment: thanks a ton. Accepted the answer. Who is Julie? my apologies as I am new to PM SE. No offense meant.

Comment: Julie is one of the members here with a huge practical knowledge of operating MS-Project. I am sure she will be along some time to offer advice. No offence taken :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show hours per resource per summary task?  Marv is spot on with the recommendation to look at the Resource Usage view.  You can also group the view on Task Summary Name to summarize the work (or cost) per task summary name.

Try creating the following group in the Resource Usage view.  The key is to set the Task Summary name to an Assignment field type.  You'll need to check the "Group assignments, not resources" check box to be able to select the Assignment field type.

[image]